# wxSplitterWindow does not show sash

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm using wxPython to build a simple app, and I'd like to use a layout like this

```
________
|   |   |
|   |___|
|   |   |
|   |   |
---------
```

This is my sample code

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title=title)
        self.Maximize()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.leftSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        self.leftSplitter.SetSashInvisible(False)  # not working
        self.rightSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.leftSplitter, style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        self.rightSplitter.SetSashInvisible(False)  # not working

        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel(self.leftSplitter)
        self.rightPanel = wx.Panel(self.rightSplitter)
        self.bottomPanel = wx.Panel(self.rightSplitter)

        self.leftSizer = wx.GridSizer(10, 4, 3, 3)
        self.rightSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.bottomSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        rightBtn = wx.Button(self.rightPanel, label="I'm on the right")
        leftBtn = wx.Button(self.leftPanel, label="I'm on the left")
        bottomBtn = wx.Button(self.bottomPanel, label="I'm on the bottom")

        self.leftSizer.Add(leftBtn)
        self.rightSizer.Add(rightBtn)
        self.bottomSizer.Add(bottomBtn)

        self.leftPanel.SetSizer(self.leftSizer)
        self.rightPanel.SetSizer(self.rightSizer)
        self.bottomPanel.SetSizer(self.bottomSizer)

        self.rightSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.rightPanel, self.bottomPanel)
        self.rightSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        self.leftSplitter.SplitVertically(self.leftPanel, self.rightSplitter)
        self.leftSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)


app = wx.App()
frame = MainWindow("My Window")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When I run it, everything works as expected, except for the fact that the sash (aka the separator) is not showing by default.
Indeed if I run

```
self.leftSplitter.IsSashVisible()
```

I get False. How can I set sash visible by default? And if make it invisible with SetSashInvisible(), how do I set it back to visible?

Comment: This code works on Linux `wx` version 4.1.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5, so you had better include details of your Operating system and version of `wx` and hope someone can replicate your environment.

Comment: Sure, I didn't know that was necessary. What kind of details do I need to insert in order to make that happen?

Comment: Your OS and the result of `python -c "import wx; print(wx.version())"` should be enough. Note: when replying start with the @ sign and the persons name, that flags that there is a message.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony good, thanks for the tip! My os is Window 10, wx version is '4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5'